# MIPS Calculator, Outputting all answers

Tags: mips

I've got an issue with my MIPS calculator in which when I enter in the two integers and choose an operator for example + it outputs all the operators instead of just the one I chose. I'm using the hex table for the number it chooses to get what the user inputted for the operator.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

```
.data
number1: .asciiz
number2: .asciiz
calculator: .asciiz         "E to exit, + to add, - to subtract, * to multiply, / to divide"
op: .asciiz " " 
.text
li $v0, 4           
la $a0, number1         
syscall             
li $v0, 5           
syscall             
move $t0, $v0           

li $v0, 4           
la $a1, number2     
syscall             
li $v0, 5           
syscall             
move $t1, $v0           

li $v0, 8           
la $a1, op          
li $a1, 2           
syscall             
lb $t2, op          

beq $t2, 43, addd       
beq $t2, 45, subtract       
beq $t2, 42, multiply       
beq $t2, 47, divide         
beq $t2, 101, exit      

addd: add $a0, $t0, $t1     
li $v0, 1           
syscall             

subtract: sub $a0, $t0, $t1     
li $v0, 1           
syscall             

multiply: mul $a0, $t0, $t1     
li $v0, 1           
syscall             

divide: div $a0, $t0, $t1   
li $v0, 1           
syscall             

exit: li $v0, 10        
syscall
```

Comment: Of course it does; there are no branches to alter the code flow after a result has been printed. You need to explicitly jump to wherever you want to go at that point.

Comment: Iv'e added branches to branch to the operation if the ascii table entry is equal. beq

Comment: Right, but after you've executed the intended piece of code you don't jump anywhere else. The CPU will just go on executing everything that follows until you explicitly tell it to not do that.

Comment: When I jump after each operation to the exit operation. It will skip all the other operations. Lets say I want to use the - operation, it will use the + operation instead.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. In the code you've shown us you don't _"jump after each operation to the exit operation"_.

Comment: No I haven't added that code, but when I do it doesn't work. I add "j exit" after each operation and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, you're calling system call 8 incorrectly. The buffer address should go into `$a0`, not `$a1`.

Comment: Likewise, `la $a1, number2` is incorrect.

Comment: I've changed the $a1's to $a0 but no change in output

Comment: Works fine for me in MARS with all those changes.